# How to enable multi-touch gestures on Lenovo Thinkpad W510 w/touchscreen - 12.04 w/Unity

Tags: unity, multi-touch, touchscreen

I am wondering how the user in this video got his W510 configured to use multi-touch with his touchscreen. I did a sudo apt-get install utouch but I need some handholding in where to go next. http://youtu.be/8Vwt11GMc3g

Much appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever get multi-touch working?

Answer (score 1):

I think in the gestures in the video are all based on a single touch which is acting as a mouse. You could configure those gestures using **Easystroke Gesture Recognition** application which is available from the repository.

I just received my X220 multitouch tablet and [asked a question about ways to improve multitouch in Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115220/how-do-i-make-thinkpad-x220t-tablet-with-multitouch-screen-rock-with-ubuntu-12-0/132023#132023), you might be interested in that question as well as hopefully more answers will be provided, or I figure things out.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and link to your question. It is helpful to know that you think it is just single touch gestures. I will follow your thread and experience as it will be similar to mine I think.

Comment: Okay I finally got Easystroke up and running and it works nicely. I can't seem to get multitouch working by default though, guess I have some more reading to do.