# How can I use multitouch apps in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: unity, 12.04, multi-touch

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on a lenovo X220 tablet and I want to get a feel of what multitouch applications/games are available. I installed anything mentioning multitouch from the repository, for example here are some of the game I installed:

- Planarity
- Multitet
- Sponc
- EMPCommand

However, my multitouch input is not correctly being registered by these application. In some cases touch inputs show at the very edges of the screen regardless of where I touch and in some other cases no input seem to be registered or at least visible in the game. I dont know yet if this is a bug or if I am missing an application or setting.

I tried calibrating the multitouch device using *Calibrate Touchscreen* tool, but that did not resolve this issue.

Here is some more information about my multitouch device. First let look at the output of xinput list:

```
:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                  id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom ISDv4 E6 Pen stylus                   id=10    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger touch                 id=11    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                       id=14    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom ISDv4 E6 Pen eraser                   id=16    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                  id=13    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                       id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard                 id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                                id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                   id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                                id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera                           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard                id=12    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                      id=15    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

The multitouch screen is being registered as a pointer device. Right now `evtest` or `ntview` can not access the device yet.

Next, I disabled the xinput device:

```
~$ xinput set-prop 11 'Device Enabled' 0
```

Now evtest is able to access the touch events. Here is a example snippet of the output, I was touching the top left corner area:

```
Event: time 1336532858.731191, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y), value 62
Event: time 1336532858.731201, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1336532859.983263, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 35
Event: time 1336532859.983265, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y), value 61
Event: time 1336532859.983272, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 33
Event: time 1336532859.983274, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1336532860.663216, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 36
Event: time 1336532860.663218, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y), value 58
```

Also mtview works now, here is a snippet from its output:

```
:~$ sudo mtview /dev/input/event13
map: 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1366.000000 768.000000
map: 50.000000 52.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1366.000000 768.000000
map: 634.000000 52.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1366.000000 768.000000
map: 99.000000 74.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1366.000000 768.000000
map: 49.000000 52.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1366.000000 768.000000
map: 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1366.000000 768.000000
map: 49.000000 52.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1366.000000 768.000000
map: 49.000000 24.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1366.000000 768.000000
```

In the mtview painting based interface, I can brush with a maximum of two fingers, so my guess is that this multitouch device doesnt really support more that two simultaneous touch events, but I am not 100% sure about that yet.

The pointer decive based on multitouch input seems to work perfectly fine and I can interact with non-multitouch applications. However none of the applications that are built to use multitouch input seem to work yet.

Disclaimer: I had [mentioned this issue in another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115220/how-do-i-make-thinkpad-x220t-tablet-with-multitouch-screen-rock-with-ubuntu-12-0) previously, but then I realized it was probably worthy of its own question.

Comment: I have the same device, and when I tested it mtview was able to recognize up to 5 simultaneous events (IIRC, but more than 2 for sure). Apart from that I cannot help you much, but am interested in the answer to this, too.

Comment: 12.04 is EOL. This question has no answers. VTC as `not reproducible`

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I asked this question 5 years ago. I am not expecting an answer now. Not sure why you are commenting on it now.

Comment: @Aras my comment is the reason to close the question. It now gives you the opportunity to plead to keep it open. You have a 5 day grace period more or less to do so.